# Debian: Create compressed Harddrive for copy

Tags: debian, hard-disk, dd, compression

On my Debian system I have a box with certain configuration settings that I like but I've had to change them continuously. There have been times that I've gotten into a some-what irreversible position.

Q: how do I create a compressed copy of my hard drive so that I can put it on external storage and reuse it. I think there's a way to use `dd` but then I want to compress it too to reduce the size to only have in the file that which I need.

Comment: What's your exact problem? The copy part, the compression? `gzip </dev/sdX >backup.img.gz` should be sufficient. If it's not what you're after, please add more detailed information.

Comment: @Marco Storing the unused space is a waste of time and space. There are better tools for the job.

Comment: @Gilles You're talking about file system awareness? Then [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) would do the job.

Comment: `gzip` would compress the unused space quite nicely, would it not?

Comment: I'll try the first line; that's exactly what I wanted assuming it works

Comment: @DopeGhoti That depends on how the unused space looks like. It's perfectly acceptable to have random (means uncompressable) data as unused space. Filesystems don't zero out unused space, so it's whatever data was stored there at some point.

Comment: Fair point, @Marco

Answer (score 0):

Why not simpley back up the files with something like Back in Time or Duplicity (or just plain rsync). The actual position of the 1s and 0s on the drive are usually not important. Duplicity (and it's front ends) have options for compression.

Answer (score 0):

A simple compressed copy can be created with

```
gzip </dev/sdX >backup.img.gz
```

or if you are CPU bound you can use [`pigz`](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/), a multithreaded `gzip` implementation to speed things up.

A more sophisticated solution would be to use tools like [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which understands most popular file systems and doesn't copy more data than actually used, in contrast to the `gzip` solution, which always copies the entire hard drive.

> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program […] Clonezilla saves and restores only used blocks in the harddisk. This increases the clone efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone else ending up here looking for a somewhat updated answer:

I'd suggest first running `fstrim`, and `zerofree` on all partitions you want to make a backup of. Then run `qemu-img convert -c -p -f raw -O qcow2 /dev/sdX /somewhere/you/want/your/backup.qcow2`.

The `qcow2` (QEMU Copy-On-Write, version 2) format is a great open source disk image format with support for dynamic allocation and compression. So the disk file can be mounted (with `qemu-nbd` or `guestmount`) without decompressing the image first (e.g. `gunzip disk.img.gz`).

The `-c` flag is to enforce compression on the output image, and the `-p` flag is just to show progress during conversion.

`fstrim` and `zerofree` are to wipe any unused disk space in hopes of better compression ratio.